# Prevent Tikz externalize from rebuilding figures

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-external

I am using Tikz externalize for the figures in a manuscript. The original files containing the Tikz/pgfplots code have been deleted (but will be regenerated in several hours when my simulations finish running).

In the meantime, I would like to make a few changes to the text and give it to someone else to review. I still have the output files from the previous Tikz compilation. Is there a way to prevent Tikz from trying to rebuild these files and instead use them as is?

Comment: Does it help to set `up to date check = simple`? In that case only figures that have no PDF version will be included ...

Answer (score 1):

This **is** possible, when you at least provide some dummy `tikz;` commands or `\begin{tikzpicture} \end{tikzpicture}` environments.

You didn't provide an example on how your TikZ code looks like, so I cannot suggest how you should do it in detail. Because you where writing about "finishing simulations" and that you are using PGFPlots I assume that you want to show some plots of simulation results. Optimally you store just the **data** in some data files and plot them like `\addplot table {<filename>};`. Then it could/should only happen that these data files are deleted during the simulation is running, but the `tikzpicture` environment itself is still present. Then the below solution will perfectly work for you.

For more details please have a look at the comments in the code and at the [section "Using the Library Without PGF or PGFPlots Installed" in the PGFPlots manual on page 530 (v1.14)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=530).

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% use this block to externalize your figures
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        % at present the PGFPlots External library is newer as the one in
        % TikZ so I use this one
        % (some bugs are fixed in it)
        pgfplots.external,
    }
    \tikzexternalize[
        % Because I think it is good practice to give your to externalize
        % pictures a name, I use the following option
        only named=true,
    ]
%% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% use this block after externalizing
%% the only thing that needs to be present is either a `\tikz ...' command
%% or a `tikzpicture environment'
%% (copy the file
%%  <tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_tikzexternal.sty>
%% into the directory of your main file (\jobname) and rename it to
%% "tikzexternal.sty")
%\usepackage{tikzexternal}
%% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % store the externalized files in the following folder
    % (this folder must already exist; otherwise you will get an error)
    \tikzsetexternalprefix{Pics/pgf-export/}
\begin{document}
    \tikzsetnextfilename{test}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
% -----------------------------------------------
% this part can be commented, deleted or whatever
% after externalization and further use of the
% `tikzexternal' package
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot coordinates { (0,0) };
        \end{axis}
% -----------------------------------------------
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
```

with

```
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikzexternal}
%\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
```

Since you didn't provide an example and I've never done this, this is untested. However, it it the method described in **50.5
 Using External Graphics Without PGF Installed** in the Ti*k*Z manual, which also discusses its use to speed compilations. See the discussion there for the limitations of this method. There are a couple of things you need to be sure to do in a particular way rather than another way, where the `external` library and Ti*k*Z themselves support multiple ways to achieve the same thing.

If you are using `pgfplots`, you should consult its manual instead of the PGF/Ti*k*Z one as you are presumably using its externalisation facilities rather than the generic ones. See [Stefan Pinnow's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/335898/) in this case as the process seems much less straightforward than in the ordinary way of things.

Otherwise, try [Tobi's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228933/prevent-tikz-externalize-from-rebuilding-figures#comment823578_228933).