# Avoid remake of references in TikZ externalization

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-external

I am working on a large document with considerably more than 100 TikZ-pictures. Within the document individual plots created with pgfplots are referenced using e.g.:

```
\addplot table[x=f,y=T]{\datPath};\label{pl:one}
```

and

```
\ref{pl:one}
```

For some reason, externalization of these references fails when I build the document as a whole. To overcome this issue, I built the documents in parts an manually renumbered the externalized reference images. So I got the files

> Dissertation-figure_crossref0.pdf
> ...
> Dissertation-figure_crossref124.pdf

in the correct order for usage in the overall document. If I rebuild the document now, TikZ tries to externalize the references again, fails at doing so and then uses the already existing images as intended. The result is correct. However, the process of trying to externalize the references takes quite a long time (about 10 minutes). Is there a way to prevent TikZ from trying to re-externalize the reference images? I tried the option

```
\tikzexternalize[up to date check=simple]
```

but to no avail.

Comment: if you have saved the pdf files you don't need to use tikzexternalize (or even tikz) at all, just `\includegraphics{Dissertation-figure_crossref0.pdf}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This approach would make the document quite inflexible regarding changes in my TikZ figures. Right now, if I modify a plot I can recompile the corresponding section and replace the reference image files. In the document I can directly refer to the plots via the assigned labels. This gets lost when switching to  ```\includegraphics```.

Comment: yes sure but it answers the question in the title (you could arrange for \label/\ref to work though) but with no example provided I couldn't follow your description of exactly how you have externalize set up or what you want to change.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I agree with David that it would be much easier to help you, if you would an [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). To avoid the renaming of the externalized stuff you could give them directly a suitable name with `\tikzsetnextfilename`. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/335898/95441.